# How to click on a descendant li element with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am automating with selenium and reached a point where I click a drop down and there are 3 options and they are in a ul list, and each option is an li role. I am able to locate them and selenium can see them but selenium cannot click on them, it says it is not interactable.

Here is the code that is interacting with it.

```
browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="ext4-ext-gen1136"]').click()

browser.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='#boundlist-1078-listEl > ul > li:nth-child(3)').click()
```

(normally I use XPATH for everything but I figured I would try CSS Selector)

Here is the HTML code

```
<ul class="x4-list-plain"><li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x4-boundlist-item x4-boundlist-selected">Show Latest Event</li><li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x4-boundlist-item">Show All Events and Traces</li><li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x4-boundlist-item">Show All Events</li></ul>
       <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x4-boundlist-item x4-boundlist-selected">Show 
        Latest Event</li>
       <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x4-boundlist-item">Show All Events and 
        Traces</li>
       <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x4-boundlist-item">Show All Events</li>
```

I want to be able to select show all events and traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to have the drop down open to click on them but the dropdown would immediately close when selenium clicked on it, all I had to do was make selenium click on it twice and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your code trials as per the value of the *`id`* attribute i.e. ***ext4-ext-gen1136*** it seems the element is a dynamic element.

---

To click on the `<li>` element with text as ***Show All Events*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.x4-list-plain li:nth-child(3)"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='x4-list-plain']//li[@class='x4-boundlist-item' and text()='Show All Events']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```